# How can I detect click outside a dynamically generated element in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have been working on an SPA with **React 18** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**. I am curenly working on the search functionality.

There is a list of search results, as seen below.

[image]

For a nice scrollbar on this list, I use **[React-Perfect-Scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-perfect-scrollbar)**.

I need this list to disapear when I click outside it.

For this purpose, in `Searchbox.jsx`, I have:

```
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar'
import { ReactComponent as Magnifier } from '../../icons/magnifier.svg';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Searchitem from './Searchitem';

function Searchbox() {

  const API_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  let [isSearch, setIsSearch] = useState(Boolean);
  const timeOutInterval = 500;
  const searchResultsContainer = useRef(null);

  const doMovieSearch = async (e) => {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);

    if (e.target.value.length >= 3) {
      setIsSearch(true);

      const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/search/movie`, {
        params: {
          api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
          query: e.target.value
        }
      });

      setResults(results);
    } else {
      setIsSearch(false);
    }
  }

  const debounceMovieSearch = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => doMovieSearch(e), timeOutInterval);
  }

  const hideSearchResults = () => {
    setIsSearch(false);
  }

  const handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
    if (!searchResultsContainer.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setIsSearch(false);
    } else {
      setIsSearch(true);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick, true);
  }, [])

  return (
    <form className="search_form w-100 mx-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <div className="input-group">
        <input className="form-control search-box" type="search" defaultValue={searchInput} onKeyUp={debounceMovieSearch} placeholder="Search movies..." />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button className="btn" type="button">
            <Magnifier />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      {isSearch ?
        <PerfectScrollbar ref={searchResultsContainer} className={"search-results shadow-sm" + (results.length ? ' with-results' : null)}>
          {results.length ?
            <>
              {results.map(movie => (
                <Searchitem key={movie.id} movie={movie} hideSearchResults={hideSearchResults} />
              ))}
            </> : <></>
          }

          {!results.length ?
            <>
              <p className="no-results">No movies found for this search</p>
            </> : <></>
          }
        </PerfectScrollbar> : <></>
      }
    </form>
  );
}

export default Searchbox;
```

The `handleOutsideClick` method should do that.

#### The problem

For a reason I have been unable to figure out, clicking outside the search list results in this error:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contains')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contains')

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PerfectScrollbar` component is only displayed when `isSearch` is `true`, so when that state is `false`, the `searchResultContainer` ref has no `current` value (so `null`).

You need to, either:

- deactivate the `handleClickOutside` listener when `isSearch` is `false` by using this variable in your `useEffect` dependency array (also, beware that you didn't set any cleanup function as your `useEffect` return value, which you should).
- create a container component around your `PerfectScrollbar` component, which is always displayed (even if it's an empty `<div>`) and is passed to the `searchResultContainer` ref, so it's value never `null`, after the first render that is.

I found two open source implementations pf this feature, if you want to look at their source code:

- from [usehooks.com](https://usehooks.com/useclickaway)
- from [react hooks library](https://react-hooks-library.vercel.app/core/useClickOutside)

Comment: How would you do the first option?

Comment: 1. Return a cleanup function from the `useEffect` hook which removes the event listener, it will be fired before the Effect is run again.
2. Conditionally attach the event listener given the value of `isSearch`.
3. Append `isSearch` to the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook, so its callback is called when the `isSearch` value changes (because the state hook would then rerender the component).

That is pretty basic, and maybe the two libraries I linked in my answer have better approaches of doing it, so don't hesitate to read their code.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by checking if the click event is outside the (parent) form, not the search results list. This code gives a good result:

```
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar'
import { ReactComponent as Magnifier } from '../../icons/magnifier.svg';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Searchitem from './Searchitem';

function Searchbox() {

  const API_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  let [isSearch, setIsSearch] = useState(Boolean);
  const timeOutInterval = 500;
  const searchResultsContainer = useRef(null);

  const doMovieSearch = async (e) => {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);

    if (e.target.value.length >= 3) {
      setIsSearch(true);

      const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/search/movie`, {
        params: {
          api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
          query: e.target.value
        }
      });

      setResults(results);
    } else {
      setIsSearch(false);
    }
  }

  const debounceMovieSearch = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => doMovieSearch(e), timeOutInterval);
  }

  const hideSearchResults = () => {
    setIsSearch(false);
  }

  const handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
    if (!searchResultsContainer.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setIsSearch(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick, true);
    }, [])

  return (
    <form ref={searchResultsContainer} className="search_form w-100 mx-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <div className="input-group">
        <input className="form-control search-box" type="search" defaultValue={searchInput} onChange={debounceMovieSearch} placeholder="Search movies..." />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button className="btn" type="button">
            <Magnifier />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      {isSearch ?
        <PerfectScrollbar className={"search-results shadow-sm" + (results.length ? ' with-results' : null)}>
          {results.length ?
            <>
              {results.map(movie => (
                <Searchitem key={movie.id} movie={movie} hideSearchResults={hideSearchResults} />
              ))}
            </> : <></>
          }

          {!results.length ?
            <>
              <p className="no-results">No movies found for this search</p>
            </> : <></>
          }
        </PerfectScrollbar> : <></>
      }
    </form>
  );
}

export default Searchbox;
```